# How can I speed up MATALAB nested for loop (timestamp correction)?

Tags: matlab, timestamp, nested-loops, large-files

I have large data files with 10Hz resolution which have been split up into half hour files. Each half hour file should contain 18000 rows. However, this is not usually the case and there are gaps in the time stamps due to datalogging errors.

In order to be able to process this data further, I need uniform data files with exactly 18000 rows each. I have written a script in MATLAB which solves this problem by using a generated full timestamp for each half hour period. Where there are gaps in the original timestamp, I fill the rows with NaNs (except the timestamp row).

Using a simple example, here is the code:

```
 Fs=1:10;  % uniform timestamp
 Fs=Fs';   %'//<-- prevents string markdown

 Ts=[1 3 7 2 1; 3 4 3 3 2;6 5 2 1 3];   %Ts is the original data with the timestamp in the first column
 Corrected=zeros(length(Fs),6);        % corrected is the data after applying uniform timestamp

 for ii=1:length(Fs)
     for jj=1:length (Ts(:,1))
         if Fs(ii)==Ts(jj)
             Corrected(ii,:)=[Fs(ii) Ts(jj,:)];
             break
         else
             Corrected(ii,:)=[Fs(ii), NaN*[ii,1:4]];

    continue
        end
    end
 end
```

The code works well enough but when I apply it to the 10Hz data, it is extremely slow. Any ideas on how I can improve this code?

Note that in the actual code I compare date strings:

```
if sum(Fs_str(ii,:)==Ts_str(jj,:))==23
             Corrected(ii,:)=[Fs(ii) Ts(jj,:)];
```

Comment: It's probably faster to change from `datestr` to `datenum`, to compare numerical values instead of strings. The result should be the same, since you sum the number of equalities anyway.

Comment: @Adriaan thanks for your response. Using datenum takes almost half the time to process 1 file (~13min vs ~25min using datestr). However I lose more data when I compare datenums because of the higher precision of datenum.

Comment: Thinking again: `datenum` are fractions of days since a reference day, so if your tolerance'd be 10 seconds, you can find the day-fraction of that: `10/(24*60*60)` and use that as a tolerance. Probably better suited than comparing full vectors as returned by `datevec`.